# Create app bar for android

Tags: android, react-native

Imagine I have an application with StackNavigator, that is when user clicks something on Page 1 he/she is redirected to Page 2 (using Stack Navigator), etc.
I want to have an app bar, which is global per the application, that is, each page (Page 1, Page2, etc.) should show this app bar.
This is what is meant by app bar.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I found a component on documentation which looks like this:

```
<ToolbarAndroid
      logo={require('./app_logo.png')}
      title="AwesomeApp"
      actions={[{title: 'Settings', icon: require('./icon_settings.png'), show: 'always'}]}
      onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected} />
```

Does it mean I need to put this component **inside** render of each page separately? (Page 1, Page2). Like I said I want only a single toolbar for whole app.

Can someone show me some code example how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate component called `MyHeader.js` and import to a file you want to use it. Give props to customize it. Example that used [NativeBase](https://nativebase.io/):

> MyHeader.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Left, Body, Right, Title, Button, Icon } from 'native-base';
import styles from '../assets/style';

export default class MyHeader extends React.Component {
render() {
    const goBack = this.props.goBackProp;
    return (
        <Container>
          <Header>
            <Left>
              <Button
                transparent
                onPress={() => goBack()}
              >
                <Icon name="ios-arrow-back" />
              </Button>
            </Left>
            <Body>
              <Title> {this.props.title} </Title>
            </Body>
            <Right />
          </Header>
        </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Now I could import it to any component like this:

```
import MyHeader from '../components/MyHeader';

export default class BlogScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {goBack} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
          <MyHeader goBackProp={goBack} title={'Blog'}/>
    );

  }
}
```